# React state updated before making a call to the function that updates it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a situation where I am passing params from Child Class to Parent on callback. Even before the Parent call executes the part where the state update has to happen, the state is already updated before that part is executed. For example, in the code below, the first console.log statement already has an updated value of state variable x set to the new one in the Parent class. This is very surprising.

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ...this.props,
        };
        this.handleCallback = this.handleCallback.bind(this);
    }
    
    handleCallback = (x) => {
        console.log('1 CALLBACK in Parent', this.state);
        this.setState({x});
        console.log('2 CALLBACK in Parent', this.state);
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Child onSubmit={this.handleCallback}>
        )
    }
}
```

```
export default class Child extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            x: {
                y: 1,
                z: 2
            }
        }; 
    }

    handleInputChange = event => {
        const {name, value} = event.target;
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            x: {
                ...prevState.x, 
                [name]: value
            }
        }));
    };
    
    handleSubmit = event => {
        this.props.onSubmit(this.state.x);
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            .
            // update to {this.state.x} happens here in input form
            <input className='inputText' type='text' name='y' placeholder={this.state.x.y} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            <input className='inputText' type='text' name='z' placeholder={this.state.x.z} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            .
        )
    }
}
```

I am wondering what could be going on wrong here and what is the best practice here ?

Comment: What are the props you are copying into the state in the parent component?

Comment: Props to the Parent are coming from its parent, a state variable and an onChange function.

Comment: I am guessing, you are passing more props to your child? Please show them too. If not, then what is x in child where areyou getting it from?

Comment: Updated the Child Component in the above code. There are no props in the Child Component. The state variable x has nested variables that are updated `onChange` event in the input fields of the form.

Comment: Try adding `value = {this.state.x.y}` to your input